# Installed PYSWIP but when trying to import it shows "module doesnt exist"

Tags: python, python-3.x, prolog

I installed pyswip in Linux Mint using the command:

```
pip install pyswip
```

However whenever I try to import pyswip as follows:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
```

I get: No module named 'pyswip'

Why is this happening? 
I have SWI-Prolog version 8.0.3

Comment: Forgot to mention it works fine for Python2, I just get the error for Python3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the platform you will need to use pip3 to install for python3. If you are on windows your path may just be pointed to the wrong pip location.

Comment: I use Linux Mint, however that worked just fined. Now its installed. Thanks a lot!